Can a repeater change frequencies on purpose?
Is it possible for a repeater to receive waves in one frequency and re-transmit them in another?
For example: Let's say I have a hand-radio that can only output frequencies in the 2-meter band. Can a repeater re transmit those 2m waves in the 40m band (after doing some "wave possessing")?
Thanks in advance

In the US, FCC regulations limit repeater operation to 10m and shorter wavelength bands.  Thus, in your example of retransmitting  in the 40m band it might be technically feasible, it would not be legal.

There certainly are cross-band repeaters, including several mobile radios that can do it. But the ones I recall are UHF bands only.


Is it possible for a repeater to receive waves in one frequency and re-transmit them in another?

That's what they often do, yes.
Re-emitting on the same frequency is problematic, because it's hard to then tell the signal that you wanted to repeat from what you're emitting, and you end up in a feedback loop. (Just like if you held the microphone attached to an amplifier to the speaker attached to the output of that amplifier: you get a loud noise, and not much else)

Makes total sense! I didn't have the feedback loop in mind. And is the re-transmission on the different band done?

yes, as I said.

FCC regulations prohibit cross band operation between bands with different licensing rules.  So while this is possible, it isn't legal.  For example, cross band from 2m to 70cm is legal, but 2m to 40m is not.   40m to 2m might be legal if it is unidirectional and 40m is not used to transmit.
Additionally, as pointed out in comments, it is not legal to put a repeater on 40m.

OP did not say they were in the US, so the FCC rules might or might not apply to them

If you are aware of rules for other countries that are different, you should post an answer covering that!

no, I'm not; and even if I were, I think the right thing to do is ask the asker what their country is, not to answer a question they might not be asking ("how is the legal situation in San Marino" is a good question, just unlikely to be the one that's being asked, and we're not an encyclopedia, but a Q&A site. "How is the legal situation in the US" is more likely to be the question being asked, but there's far more hams outside the US than inside, so probably still not what they are wondering about)
